# Error while converting function from oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, plsql

I am migrating a function from Oracle to SQL Server 2008. This function raises `SELECT` statements included within a function cannot return data to a client as error. How can I solve this problem?

Original PLSQL Code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function f_birim_cevrim_katsayi (p_ID_MAMUL in number, p_ID_BIRIMDEN in number, p_ID_BIRIME in number) 
return number
is

v_katsayi number;

begin

v_katsayi:=0;

if p_ID_BIRIMDEN!=p_ID_BIRIME then

    for c in (
         select * from CR_BIRIM_CEVRIM
         where ID_MAMUL = p_ID_MAMUL
         and (
         (ID_BIRIM = p_ID_BIRIMDEN and ID_BIRIM2 = p_ID_BIRIME)
         OR ( ID_BIRIM2 = p_ID_BIRIMDEN and ID_BIRIM = p_ID_BIRIME) )
         and VALID = 1) 
         loop

         if c.ID_BIRIM=p_ID_BIRIMDEN then
            v_katsayi:=c.MT_ORAN;
         else
            v_katsayi:=1/c.MT_ORAN;
         end if;
    end loop;
else
    v_katsayi:=1;
end if;

return round(v_katsayi,10);

exception 
when others then 
return 0;

end;
```

T-SQL code:

```
If Exists ( SELECT name 
                FROM sysobjects  
                WHERE name = 'f_birim_cevrim_katsayi'
                AND type = 'FN')
        DROP FUNCTION f_birim_cevrim_katsayi
    GO 
    CREATE FUNCTION f_birim_cevrim_katsayi
    (
        @p_ID_MAMUL                               FLOAT ,
        @p_ID_BIRIMDEN                            FLOAT ,
        @p_ID_BIRIME                              FLOAT 
    )
    RETURNS float 
    AS 
        BEGIN


            DECLARE @adv_error INT


            DECLARE @v_katsayi                                FLOAT 
            SELECT @v_katsayi  = 0 
            IF @p_ID_BIRIMDEN != @p_ID_BIRIME 
            BEGIN 


                DECLARE cursor_for_inline_select1 CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
                SELECT *
                FROM  CR_BIRIM_CEVRIM 
                WHERE    ID_MAMUL  = @p_ID_MAMUL
                 AND    ((ID_BIRIM  = @p_ID_BIRIMDEN
                 AND    ID_BIRIM2  = @p_ID_BIRIME)
                 OR (ID_BIRIM2  = @p_ID_BIRIMDEN
                 AND    ID_BIRIM  = @p_ID_BIRIME))
                 AND    VALID  = 1

                OPEN cursor_for_inline_select1 

                FETCH NEXT FROM  cursor_for_inline_select1  
                WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
                BEGIN
                    IF   c.ID_BIRIM = @p_ID_BIRIMDEN 
                    BEGIN 
                        SELECT @v_katsayi  = c.MT_ORAN 
                    END
                    ELSE
                    BEGIN 
                        SELECT @v_katsayi  = 1/c.MT_ORAN 
                    END

                END
                CLOSE cursor_for_inline_select1
                DEALLOCATE cursor_for_inline_select1

            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN 
                SELECT @v_katsayi  = 1 
            END


     DEALLOCATE cursor_for_inline_select1
            return ROUND(@v_katsayi, 10) 
            GOTO ExitLabel1
            Exception1:

                BEGIN

     DEALLOCATE cursor_for_inline_select1
                return 0 
                            END
            ExitLabel1:

            return ROUND(@v_katsayi, 10) 

        END


    GO
```

Comment: How many rows to you expect in the CURSOR?

Comment: why don't you add the original plsql code?

Comment: i edited and added original plsql code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [CREATE FUNCTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186755.aspx)

> Cursor operations referencing local
>   cursors that are declared, opened,
>   closed, and deallocated in the
>   function. Only FETCH statements that
>   assign values to local variables using
>   the INTO clause are allowed; FETCH
>   statements that return data to the
>   client are not allowed

This means this is wrong

```
DECLARE cursor_for_inline_select1 CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
            SELECT *
            FROM  CR_BIRIM_CEVRIM 
            WHERE    ID_MAMUL  = @p_ID_MAMUL
             AND    ((ID_BIRIM  = @p_ID_BIRIMDEN
             AND    ID_BIRIM2  = @p_ID_BIRIME)
             OR (ID_BIRIM2  = @p_ID_BIRIMDEN
             AND    ID_BIRIM  = @p_ID_BIRIME))
             AND    VALID  = 1
```

You are not assigning the CURSOR output to local variables.

Please describe what you want to do with sample data: I'm sure this is a simple SELECT with a CASE

Edit: You don't need a CURSOR unless my pl/sql is *way* off

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_birim_cevrim_katsayi (
    @p_ID_MAMUL                               FLOAT ,
    @p_ID_BIRIMDEN                            FLOAT ,
    @p_ID_BIRIME                              FLOAT 
)
RETURNS float 
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @v_katsayi FLOAT;
    IF @p_ID_BIRIMDEN != @p_ID_BIRIME 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT
             @v_katsayi =  CASE
                 WHEN ID_BIRIM = @p_ID_BIRIMDEN THEN c.MT_ORAN 
                 ELSE 1/c.MT_ORAN 
             END
        FROM 
             CR_BIRIM_CEVRIM c
        WHERE
             ID_MAMUL  = @p_ID_MAMUL
             AND    ((ID_BIRIM  = @p_ID_BIRIMDEN
             AND    ID_BIRIM2  = @p_ID_BIRIME)
             OR (ID_BIRIM2  = @p_ID_BIRIMDEN
             AND    ID_BIRIM  = @p_ID_BIRIME))
             AND    VALID  = 1;
    END
    RETURN ROUND(ISNULL(@v_katsayi, 1), 10);
END
GO
```

Comment: I think you are right. I guess what confuses us is a bad migrated no_data_found exception.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing these two lines

```
SELECT @v_katsayi  = 0 

SELECT @v_katsayi  = 1
```

to

```
SET @v_katsayi  = 0 

SET @v_katsayi  = 1
```

Missed a couple others.   Anywhere you are using SELECT to simply set a variable value, change to SET instead...

Also:  change your cursor to grab the field and put it into a variable

```
DECLARE @theID FLOAT
DECLARE @theORAN FLOAT

DECLARE cursor_for_inline_select1 CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
                SELECT id_birim,MT_ORAN  -- Fields name instead of *
                FROM  CR_BIRIM_CEVRIM 
                WHERE    ID_MAMUL  = @p_ID_MAMUL
                 AND    ((ID_BIRIM  = @p_ID_BIRIMDEN
                 AND    ID_BIRIM2  = @p_ID_BIRIME)
                 OR (ID_BIRIM2  = @p_ID_BIRIMDEN
                 AND    ID_BIRIM  = @p_ID_BIRIME))
                 AND    VALID  = 1

                OPEN cursor_for_inline_select1 
                -- Put field value into variable
                FETCH NEXT FROM  cursor_for_inline_select1  INTO @theID,@theORan
                WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
                BEGIN
                    -- Compare variable rather than field directly
                    IF   @theID = @p_ID_BIRIMDEN 
                    BEGIN 
                        SELECT @v_katsayi  = @theORan 
                    END
                    ELSE
                    BEGIN 
                        SELECT @v_katsayi  = 1/@theORan 
                    END

                END
                CLOSE cursor_for_inline_select1
                DEALLOCATE cursor_for_inline_select1
```

Comment: Just different ways of assigning variables. utterly incorrect

Comment: I agree, just a different way of assigning variables, but where else do you see a SELECT clause that is returning data in the function?  I've see the SQL parser sometimes do this, treat an assignment SELECT as a select that is returning a value...

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too.    Have a happy new year

Comment: Happy New year u too.Thanks for your help,after i copied ur solution now it gives "The multi-part identifier "c.MT_ORAN" could not be bound" error.What can i do?

Comment: I revised the Cursor to deal with the MT_ORAN field, check the revised code above.   Sorry I missed that one